# How to reopen stdin in TCL?

Tags: tcl

I am experimenting with TCL channels.

How do I re-open stdin on Linux ?

Example:

```
close stdin

... ?

gets stdin input
puts $input
```

Answer (score 2):

On Unix systems (Not sure about Windows), standard input is file descriptor 0. When a new file descriptor is created, it's assigned to the lowest unused descriptor number. So if you close `stdin`, descriptor 0 becomes available and the next `open`, `socket`, etc. that returns a tcl channel identifier will internally use file descriptor 0.

Internally, tcl has a function `CheckForStdChannelsBeingClosed()` in [`generic/TclIO.c`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/file?name=generic/tclIO.c&ci=tip) that will clear the IO object for `stdin`, `stdout`, or `stderr` in an internal per-interpreter(?) table, and another, `Tcl_GetStdChannel()` that looks in that table for the IO object for one of those streams. If the requested one is uninitialized, it calls an OS-specific routine to get the underlying stream and saves it in that internal table (Which on Unix will create one using file descriptor 0 for `stdin`).

So if you close stdin, the next file/socket/pipe/etc. opened will be treated as the new standard input.

```
close stdin ;# Free up FD#0
set foo [open input.txt r] ;# Open a file using FD#0
gets stdin line ;# Reads from input.txt
```

If you then close `$foo` in the above, reads from `stdin` will fail until you open a new file that re-uses descriptor 0.

If you wanted to reopen the *original* standard input stream... that's harder. If it was a pipe or socket, it's gone forever. If it was input from a terminal, opening `/dev/tty` might work, depending on the OS. If it was a regular file or FIFO, you'd have to know the filename somehow and re-open that.

Comment: FYI this question is originally motivated by a problem I was experiencing with “term::receive::bind”. Thank you for helping me solve the actual problem (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869821/gets-stdin-not-working-after-termreceivebind-in-tcl).