# "gets stdin" not working after "term::receive::bind" in TCL

Tags: tcl

In the following code, when `vwait` ends, the subsequent `gets stdin` does not prompt for input.

How do I get the `puts $input` to work ?

(Nb: script is run on Linux).

```
#/* Based on "lib/tcllib1.20/term/ipager.tcl" */

package require term::receive::bind
package require term::ansi::ctrl::unix

set done .

proc showDate {str} {
    puts [clock format [clock seconds] -format %+]
}

proc endVwait {str} {
    variable done
    set done .
}

::term::ansi::ctrl::unix::raw

#/* Event loop dispatch */
::term::receive::bind bind {d showDate q endVwait}
bind  listen
vwait done
bind  unlisten

::term::ansi::ctrl::unix::cooked

#/*
# * Problem: The following statements do not block on stdin
# */

gets stdin input
puts $input
```

Result:

```
Typing "d" displays the current date. 
Typing "q" ends the event loop and continues the script.

Expected: Script prompts for user input and displays the value of $input
  Actual: Script ends
```

**Update:**

I fixed my problem by re-opening stdin (see Shawn's answer to [How to reopen stdin in TCL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869561/how-to-reopen-stdin-in-tcl)):

```
...

close stdin
open /dev/tty

gets stdin input
puts $input
```

**Update:**

As per Donal Fellows' answer this can also be resolved with:

```
chan configure stdin -blocking 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that, after using that package, the `stdin` channel is in non-blocking mode, as if with:

```
chan configure stdin -blocking 0
```

When non-blocking, `gets` will return immediately even if there is no complete line available.

When you close and reopen it, you get a channel that is blocking; that's the default for all channels. (OTOH, you don't necessarily get the same device; `stdin` is not necessarily connected to what `/dev/tty` resolves to.)

If my diagnosis is correct, fixing things without reopening is just:

```
chan configure stdin -blocking 1
```

after putting the terminal into cooked mode. (You probably should always use blocking with cooked mode — the two are made for each other — just as raw mode usually goes best with non-blocking.)